# An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist - Springboot: Maven

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml, google-cloud-logging

So I'm having a little bit of an issue with a project, the following error appears while trying to start a Spring Boot application:

```
An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    com.google.cloud.logging.v2.stub.LoggingServiceV2StubSettings$Builder.createDefault(LoggingServiceV2StubSettings.java:634)

The following method did not exist:

    'com.google.api.gax.rpc.StubSettings$Builder com.google.cloud.logging.v2.stub.LoggingServiceV2StubSettings$Builder.setMtlsEndpoint(java.lang.String)'

The method's class, com.google.cloud.logging.v2.stub.LoggingServiceV2StubSettings$Builder, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/home/mantes/.m2/repository/com/google/cloud/google-cloud-logging/2.3.2/google-cloud-logging-2.3.2.jar!/com/google/cloud/logging/v2/stub/LoggingServiceV2StubSettings$Builder.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    com.google.cloud.logging.v2.stub.LoggingServiceV2StubSettings.Builder: file:/home/mantes/.m2/repository/com/google/cloud/google-cloud-logging/2.3.2/google-cloud-logging-2.3.2.jar
    com.google.api.gax.rpc.StubSettings.Builder: file:/home/sebastian/.m2/repository/com/google/api/gax/1.54.0/gax-1.54.0.jar

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of com.google.cloud.logging.v2.stub.LoggingServiceV2StubSettings$Builder
```

Now, I have read something online and it appears to be a problem related to either:

- An incompatibility between libraries versions.
- An unnecessary duplication of libraries.

In both cases it's something maven/pom related, I've tried deleting the .m2 files but nothing really changes also tried to find if there where some duplicated of libraries and excluding what I thought could be causing the problem but again, nothing, also I've build this project into a docker image and after running it the problem still appears (wasn't expecting it to solve the problem but at least can give a hint as to why I'm having this issue). So, I'm kinda at a loss here, not sure how to proceed

Important parts in the POM:

```
<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <google-cloud.version>19.2.1</google-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-logging</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
     <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>          
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${google-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

EDIT:
So, I solved the issue thanks to @M. Deinum and @xerx593, it was indeed an error caused by dependency override handled poorly, the error I received by removing the version was caused by a totally different issue that I associated with what I had just changed. Anyways removing the version from google-cloud-logging indeed solved the problem, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Remove the version from `google-cloud-logging` you alredy import the bom which manages the versions.

Comment: So, I have tried that too, but i just causes a new error: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.integration.inbound.PubSubInboundChannelAdapter]: Factory method 'inboundChannelAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pub/Sub subscription name can't be null.

Comment: hi & welcome! `java.version` has no special meaning in maven ... do you use some parent pom?

Comment: taking this pom snippet to a "quickstart" project, I get: "Overrides version in dependency management" warning (+ dep. conflicts) for the `<version>2.3.2</version>` quick fixes: 1. remove explicit version declaration (2. upgrade to 3.11.1 (current))

Comment: Please don't add additional information stacktraces as comments as those are totally unreadable. What I can decipher is that you apparently now have a configuration issue which is something you should solve. Have you read upgrade/migration guides?